# Работа с stdClass Object ( )

Tags: php

Есть переменная $places, где хранится объект:

```
stdClass Object ( [row1] => 1 [seet1] => 3 [row2] => 1 [seet2] => 4 )
```

Как можно вывести/сохранить в переменную определенную часть объекта?
Пробовал так, но не получается

```
echo $places['seet1'];
```

И как вывести количество элементов? Пробовал так, но выводит только 1:

```
echo count($places);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так это же объект, следственно и обращаться с ним нужно как с объектом:

```
echo $places->seet1;
```

Для того чтобы использовать count(), вы можете воспользоваться [get_object_vars()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.get-object-vars.php), либо если по каким-то причинам этот вариант не подходит, то преобразовать объект в массив:

```
// Вариант 1
echo count(get_object_vars($places));

// Вариант 2
echo count((array)$places);
```

Comment: Премного благодарен

Comment: Еще один вопрос, как можно в цикле с помощью переменной $i изменять названия элементов? 
`for($i=1; $i<=$place_number; $i++){
$row=($places->row.$i)-1;  
$seet=($places->seet.$i)-1;    
$current_seets[$row][$seet]=false;
    }`
Это я так пытался при каждой итерации изменять массив `$current_seets`

Comment: Я не совсем понял что конкретно вам нужно поменять и что вы пытаетесь сделать. Какая, скажем так, конечная цель, для чего вы это делаете? Особенно мне не понятно вот это `$places->seet.$i` вы конкатенируете `$places->seet` и  `$i`?

Comment: Идея такова: Есть объект, который я показал выше. Она содержит элементы `row` и `seet` (row1, seet1, row2, seet2, таких может быть до 5). С данным циклом я хотел бы получить значения каждой `row` и `seet` и использовать их чтобы изменить массив. Да, как можно конкатенировать `$places->seet` и `$i`?

Comment: А вот я разобрался: `$ar_places=(array)$places; $row=($ar_places['row'.$i])-1;$seet=($ar_places['seet'.$i])-1;`
Воспользовался вашим ответом, преобразил в массив и тогда конкатенация сработала

Comment: Спасибо вам  ещё раз за уделенное время!